# FB.login triggers a different popup layout for different accounts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a facebook app that uses the facebook Jaascript SDK and calls `FB.login()` in order to grant permissions and authorize the app.

When I log in using my own account the permissions flow works as expected.

When my coworker logs in using their account the facebook popup does not ask for the permissions it is supposed to.

Also the layout in the popup is different:
[image]

What is the thing that is triggering this difference? I think it is the same thing that is preventing the permissions from being requested.

For reference, here is my `FB.login()` call:

```
    FB.login((response) => { 
        /* snip */
    }, {
        scope: 'public_profile,pages_read_engagement,pages_show_list,pages_manage_posts,instagram_basic',
        return_scopes: true,
        auth_type: 'rerequest'
    })
```

And the call is being triggered from a button click.

Comment: Does the other account have a role in the app? If not, then of course you can only ask it for these permissions, after you submitted your app for review.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add my coworkers facebook account to the "test users" list in the facebook app settings.